# NaN3 quantity for the generation of N2

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, gas-laws

> You wish to design an airbag for a car. The gas that is released must be at a pressure higher than that of air – $\pu{110 kPa}$ at a temperature of $\pu{22 ^\circ C}$. The bag that you develop can expand to a volume of $\pu{45.5 L}$. What quantity of sodium azide $\ce{NaN3}$ should be used to generate the required mas of $\ce{N2}$ gas?

I've been given this question on my revision sheet. So far I've figured out using Boyle's law that I need 2 mol of $\ce{N2}$ gas. However, I am unsure of how to transfer this over to the $\ce{NaN3}$ and use the ratio or what not to find the number of moles there.

Comment: Use $\ce{2NaN3 -> 2Na + 3N2}$ and stoichiometry to reach the final answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$\ce{2NaN3 -> 2Na + 3N2}$$

As you already found the amount of $\ce{N2}$ required, I'll just give you a hint on how to get the amount of sodium azide required to produce that much nitrogen.

We know that 2 moles of sodium azide gives us 3 moles of nitrogen. So $x$ moles of sodium azide gives us $2$ moles of nitrogen. Solve for $x$. That's all!